# Nuxt Algolia InstantSearch: implement server side rendering when the client is fetched dynamically

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, algolia, nuxtjs3

TL;DR: Is there a way to access variables created in `setup()` in `mixins` in Vue?

---

I'm new to Vue (/ Nuxt) and Algolia with vue-instantsearch. I want to add Algolia to my Nuxt 3 app.

It works so far, however only when the page is client side rendered. It doesn't work when its server side rendered. Luckily, there is [a guide for server side rendering](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/going-further/server-side-rendering/vue/#with-nuxt) vue-instantsearch in Nuxt.

In the docs it initiates the `searchClient` before the component and then uses that client in the mixin like this:

```js
// ...

const searchClient = algoliasearch(
  'latency',
  '6be0576ff61c053d5f9a3225e2a90f76'
);

export default {
  mixins: [
    createServerRootMixin({
      searchClient,
      indexName: 'instant_search',
    }),
  ],

// ...
```

However, in my case I want to restrict searches to users. (Not every user is supposed to see every entry.) Therefore, I generate the token for my users dynamically and get the `searchClient` in my `setup()`.

```js
setup() {
  const sessionSearchTokenQuery = useQuery(gqlSessionSearchToken)
  const sessionSearchToken = useResult(sessionSearchTokenQuery.result)
  const searchClient = ref<SearchClient | null>(null)
  watch(
    sessionSearchToken,
    (token) => {
      if (token?.appID && token?.clientKey) {
        searchClient.value = algoliasearch(token.appID, token.clientKey)
      }
    },
    { immediate: true }
  )
  return { searchClient, token: sessionSearchToken }
},
```

So now I don't think I can access the `searchClient` in the mixins, can I?

How can I solve this? Is there a way to fetch the client first and then initiate the mixins and pass the client to the mixins? Is there maybe a two component solution for this, where one component creates the `searchClient`, passes it to the next component, which then uses it in a mixin?

---

**Edit:** I'm onto a hacky solution.

```js
export default defineComponent({
  components: {
    SessionCardLoad,
  },
  provide() {
    return {
      $_ais_ssrInstantSearchInstance: this.instantsearch,
    }
  },
  setup() {
    const sessionSearchTokenQuery = useQuery(gqlSessionSearchToken)
    const sessionSearchToken = useResult(sessionSearchTokenQuery.result)
    const searchClient = ref<SearchClient | null>(null)
    watch(
      sessionSearchToken,
      (token) => {
        if (token?.appID && token?.clientKey) {
          searchClient.value = algoliasearch(token.appID, token.clientKey)
        }
      },
      { immediate: true }
    )
    const { data } = createServerRootMixin({searchClient, $config.MIML_STAGE + '-miml-sentences'})
    const { instantSearch } = data()
    return { searchClient, token: sessionSearchToken, instantsearch }
  },
  head() {
    return {
      link: [
        {
          rel: 'stylesheet',
          href: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/instantsearch.css@7.4.5/themes/satellite-min.css',
        },
      ],
    }
  },
})
```

Here I use the mixin within setup to get the data the mixin would usually return. And I mimic the [`provide`](https://github.com/algolia/vue-instantsearch/blob/25284aafdb95f4684387744953c2a38241da7ad1/src/util/createServerRootMixin.js#L288) step from the mixin's code.

My main problem here is accessing `$config` in the `setup()` property.

Comment: The tutorial you're using here is based on Nuxt2's CLI. Hence, if you don't use anything that enables the composition API (nuxt-bridge, `@nuxtjs/composition-api`, nuxt3 or alike), you cannot really use `setup` here. More info here about Nuxt3: https://v3.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/introduction#comparison

Comment: @kissu I'm using Nuxt 3 with the composition API.

Comment: Ah, I may have missed it. I've corrected the tag to include [tag:nuxtjs3]. I guess that the current docs of Algolia will not be really useful here. I recommend you to give a try to the Nuxt3 discussion and try to figure out how to make it work with the new API: https://github.com/nuxt/framework/discussions

Comment: @kissu I think I'm onto a hacky solution. I will edit the question  If you can, please give some feedback on it.